# BATCH CALL / FOR - cant be processed syntactically at this point

Tags: windows, batch-file

Sorry for asking, I wanted to solve it myself but don't know how to do it. I'm not a programmer, I just want to make my life easier. What this little .bat file does is, it copies a .doc file and renames it like this: %Number%_%Date%-%Date+4days%. I basically want to execute this file every monday so I get a file like "13-04_12_2017-08_12_2017.doc"

```
copy H:\foo\bar\Template.doc H:\foo\bar\temp.doc
for /f "skip=0" %%G IN (H:\foo\bar\BRNumber.txt) DO if not defined line set "BRNumber=%%G"
CALL DateMath %Date:~6,4% %Date:~3,2% %Date:~0,2% + 4
ren H:\foo\bar\temp.doc Nr.%BRNumber%_%DATE%-%_dd_str%.%_mm_str%.%_yy_int%.doc

set /a BRNumber = BRNumber + 1
(
  echo %BRNummer%
) > H:\foo\bar\BRNumber.txt
```

The Problem is, since I put the CALL line in there, the whole "for" line doesn't work -> "cant be processed syntactically at this point”

any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"skip=0"` is invalid. The `skip` amount must be 1 or greater. Omitting this quoted option should restore operation. Whether the `datemath` routine does what you expect or no - that's another question entirely...

Comment: What is the purpose of `if not defined line`?  That variable is never set in your code. The `CALL` has nothing to do with the `FOR`. They are on completely different lines.  The CMD interpreter process each line of a file before moving onto the next so the `CALL` and `FOR` have no affect on each other.  You can shorten the syntax of this line: `set /a BRNumber = BRNumber + 1` to `set /a BRNumber+=1`.